# What is the equivalent history.go(0) in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I go back to previous page without using JavaScript cause some browsers has the JavaScript off

```html
<li id="hide-lang">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    <?php echo $language; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a onClick="<php echo('history.go(0)'); ?>">Português</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="form.submit();">Espanhol</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="form.submit();">English</a></li>
  </ul>
  </a>
</li>
</li>
```

What is the equivalent `history.go(0)` in php?

Comment: Use a hidden form field.

Comment: `onClick="history.go(0)"` That's JavaScript

Comment: So you're trying to make it work for JS disabled browsers, yet your entire code is full of JavaScript. Are you expecting a translation? Or badly worded question?

Comment: What you want to do is not clear.

Comment: Where's you PHP code which you'd run to set the variable?

Comment: Amadeu, they downvoted you because you didn't show any PHP. Stackoverflow is for solving issues & fixing bugs, not for people to convert code for you. "PHP previous page URL" = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], which you can find on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Use submit buttons to send the form, and use `HTTP_REFERER` from global `$_SERVER` array to go back. This is the only way I know without javascript.

But I suggest you to make a javascript check at the page load and tell the user to turn on javascript.

```
<?php
$back = '/';
if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
    $back = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
}
?>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $back; ?>">Português</a></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Espanhol"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="English"></a></li>
</ul>
```